# Jsoup CSS Select exclude elements with attribute that has a certain value

Tags: css-selectors, jsoup

Using Jsoup CSS Selector on a html string on [Jsoup test drive](http://try.jsoup.org/), I need to extract all the input elements which do not have type="image" attribute. 
I tried few strings for no avail. input:not(.image) , input:not(type=image) , and few others after reading some of the examples [here](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html), please help, 
Thank you
example:

```
<input type="what_ever" ...>
<input type="image" ...>
```

I want to get all the

```
<input type="what_ever" .. >
```

elements only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this - `input[type=what_ever]`.

**Edit** -
Due to OP's comment, it should be `input[type!=image]`.
Tried the following input at [try.jsoup.org](http://try.jsoup.org)

```
<input type="what_ever" ...>
<input type="image" ...>
<input type="something" ...>
<input type="image" ...>
```

and the result is

```
<input type="what_ever" ...>
<input type="something" ...>
```

Comment: that will not work as what_ever could be more than one value, unless there is what_ever_1| what_ever_2, ...

Comment: Wouldn't be nice if we can do something like 'input[type=text && type!=hidden]'?

Comment: But a [type=text] is by necessity also [type!=hidden] since you can't have two different values for the same attribute on a single element...